# How to save CMake output to file?

Tags: bash, cmake, stdout, io-redirection, stderr

I can usually save the output of bash commands by `>> output_file.txt`

But when I execute `cmake` the output is still sent to the screen rather than output file as expected:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D \
BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D \
INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON  -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON .. >> output_file.txt
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That is because part (possibly all, depending on the situation) of your cmake output is streamed to stderr.

Use this to redirect stderr to stdout:

```
cmake ... >> output_file.txt 2>&1
```

or append only stderr to output_file.txt:

```
cmake ... 2>> output_file.txt
```

Comment: Some details about this can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625224/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-a-file)