# How to redirect output of CMake into a File instead of windows cmd prompt

Tags: c, batch-file, cmake

I am calculating the compiling time for a C project using CMake for compilation statistics.

Below you can see the CMake cmd's which I am using for printing the compilation time:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE "${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E time") 
set_property(TARGET ${MAIN_TARGET} PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE "${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E time")
```

This lines of code printing out in windows cmd prompt (e.g.):

```
Elapsed time: 0 s. (time), 0.000672 s. (clock)
```

So the calculation works as expected for me. But I would like to have the calculated time listed in a .txt file instead of printing it out in cmd prompt.

I found a solution here: 
[How to save CMake output to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275078/how-to-save-cmake-output-to-file)

```
cmake ... >> output_file.txt 2>&1
cmake ... 2>> output_file.txt
```

But I didn't understand how to use it for my CMake cmd's which is listed above.
I have tried it as below, but unfortunately it is not working:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE "${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E time" >> output_file.txt 2>&1) 
set_property(TARGET ${MAIN_TARGET} PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE "${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E time" >> output_file.txt 2>&1)
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You appear to be mixing the CMake commands with a `bash` command (which will not have the desired affect in Windows cmd). On Windows, you just want `cmake ... > output_file.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE` specifies a command prefix, and stream redirection goes at the end of a shell command, using it like this cannot work.

Also, commands as specified in CMake are not shell commands. This means that special characters will not be interpreted, and will just be arguments for the command.

To summerize, what you're trying to do will be expanded into something like:

```
cmake -E time >> output_file.txt 2>&1 gcc...
```

This will not be executed by a shell, but by CMake itself, so it is going to fail as time will try to execute a command named ">>".

The solution for you is to use an intermediate script, for example:

```
@echo off
time %* >> output_file.txt
```

Let's name this `trace.cmd`.
The use of `%*` means that we take all arguments to the script and pass them as arguments to the `time` command.

Then you can use it like this:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE "${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E trace.cmd")
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested the solution.